# Can googlechart query more than 1 spreadsheet at the same time?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

because I tried query 3 sheets with 3 charts at the same time with 1 handle function ,it works but the result is wrong (it display the same chart in 3 div)

So I think I have to add handle function on each chart like

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ["geochart"]});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var query1 = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14VouG7zZqHGB9CA6bxQx6CXX-TvOYkSqTmrN5DAj1Do/edit#gid=1175123524");
  
  var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RsugJPtz2EdHOLaiL0SvR9bh61H-vAgn9x1QBjIJ--c/edit?usp=sharing');
  
  var query3 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zPP22gUPLDqTrvASIU3OXpmeHL_9IBS2O4z75g-1BHY/edit?usp=sharing');
  
  query1.send(handleQueryResponseTR1);
  query2.send(handleQueryResponseTR2);
  query3.send(handleQueryResponseTR3);
 }

 function handleQueryResponseTR1(response1) {
  if (response1.isError()) {
   alert('Error in query: ' + response1.getMessage() + ' ' + response1.getDetailedMessage());
   return;
  }
  function handleQueryResponseTR2(response2) {
  if (response2.isError()) {
   alert('Error in query: ' + response2.getMessage() + ' ' + response2.getDetailedMessage());
   return;
  }
  function handleQueryResponseTR3(response3) {
  if (response3.isError()) {
   alert('Error in query: ' + response3.getMessage() + ' ' + response3.getDetailedMessage());
   return;
  }
  var data1 = response1.getDataTable();
  var data2 = response2.getDataTable();
  var data3 = response3.getDataTable();
```

but I got an error

> handleQueryResponseTR2 is not defined

So I don't know if google chart can query more than 1 sheet in one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe googlechart queries have any problems with multiple queries at the same time, to answer the question.

Regarding your code:

Your handleQueryResponseTR2 function is a local function in handleQueryResponseTR1 but you try to call it from drawRegionsMap(). handleQueryResponseTR2() is not defined in that scope.

Move handleQueryResponseTR2() to upper scope to make it visible to the calling function.

In fact, move all your handleQueryResponse functions to the upper level.

```
var data1;
var data2;
var data3;

function handleQueryResponseTR1(response1) {
    if (response1.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response1.getMessage() + ' ' + response1.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    data1 = response1.getDataTable();
}

function handleQueryResponseTR2(response2) {
    if (response2.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response2.getMessage() + ' ' + response2.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    data2 = response2.getDataTable();
}

function handleQueryResponseTR3(response3) {
    if (response3.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response3.getMessage() + ' ' + response3.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    data3 = response3.getDataTable();
}

function drawRegionsMap() {
    var query1 = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14VouG7zZqHGB9CA6bxQx6CXX-TvOYkSqTmrN5DAj1Do/edit#gid=1175123524");

    var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RsugJPtz2EdHOLaiL0SvR9bh61H-vAgn9x1QBjIJ--c/edit?usp=sharing');

    var query3 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zPP22gUPLDqTrvASIU3OXpmeHL_9IBS2O4z75g-1BHY/edit?usp=sharing');

    query1.send(handleQueryResponseTR1);
    query2.send(handleQueryResponseTR2);
    query3.send(handleQueryResponseTR3);
}
```

Please, note that the handleQueryResponse functions are called asynchronously when the responses are received.